# R finding the row in a data frame where a state transition happens?

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following data frame,

```
id, date, state
1   2012-01-01 a
1   2012-01-02 a
1   2012-01-03 a
1   2012-01-04 b
1   2012-01-05 b
2   2013-01-01 a
2   2013-01-02 a
2   2013-01-03 b
2   2013-01-04 b
```

For each id, I want to find the date when the state changed from a to b following which I want it inserted as a column for that id. So the above example would yield

```
id, date, state, changedate
1   2012-01-01 a 2012-01-03
1   2012-01-02 a 2012-01-03
1   2012-01-03 a 2012-01-03
1   2012-01-04 b 2012-01-03
1   2012-01-05 b 2012-01-03
2   2013-01-01 a 2013-01-02
2   2013-01-02 a 2013-01-02
2   2013-01-03 b 2013-01-02
2   2013-01-04 b 2013-01-02
```

Is there a way to do this elegantly through plyr functions or even in base R?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @JackManey In this instance, the example is minimal and reproducible which is sufficient for a good question.

Comment: @sebastian-c In my experience, opinions on that differ on SO. I think you'll find that many consider a simple input/output specification (no matter how reproducible), with no evidence that the OP made an attempt at all, to be low quality question. The rationale being that in the extreme, SO simply becomes a place where people can come to have their work done for them, for free, by strangers.

Comment: @sebastian-c - Incorrect. The OP has only given sample input and the requested sample output. No code was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: As Sebastian mentions, I assume that the data.frame is ordered by the column `date`.

One of the many solutions. Probably the tricky bit is to find the transition period. This can be accomplished with the help of `rle`.

```
rle.df <- rle(df$state)
# get indices of a-to-b transition -> 3,7
idx <- cumsum(rle.df$lengths)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
# get indices of b-to-a transition -> 5,9
idx2 <- cumsum(rle.df$lengths)[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
# construct appropriate lengths -> 5,4
idx2 <- c(idx2[1], diff(idx2))
# do a rep with idx2 fro times and df$date[idx] for value
df$changedate <- unlist(lapply(1:length(idx2), function(vv) {
    rep(df$date[idx[vv]], idx2[vv])
}))

> df
  id.      date. state changedate
1   1 2012-01-01     a 2012-01-03
2   1 2012-01-02     a 2012-01-03
3   1 2012-01-03     a 2012-01-03
4   1 2012-01-04     b 2012-01-03
5   1 2012-01-05     b 2012-01-03
6   2 2013-01-01     a 2013-01-02
7   2 2013-01-02     a 2013-01-02
8   2 2013-01-03     b 2013-01-02
9   2 2013-01-04     b 2013-01-02
```

Alternative solution using `data.table` (I just noticed that you also have a `.id.` column with which we can split and apply the date with the transition index found via `rle`).

```
require(data.table)
rle.df <- rle(df$state)
idx  <- cumsum(rle.df$lengths)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
idx2 <- cumsum(rle.df$lengths)[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
idx  <- c(idx[1], tail(idx, -1) - head(idx2, -1))

dt <- data.table(df, key="id.")
out <- dt[, `:=`(changedate=date.[idx[id.]]), by=id.]

> out
    id.      date. state changedate
 1:   1 2012-01-01     a 2012-01-03
 2:   1 2012-01-02     a 2012-01-03
 3:   1 2012-01-03     a 2012-01-03
 4:   1 2012-01-04     b 2012-01-03
 5:   1 2012-01-05     b 2012-01-03
 6:   2 2013-01-01     a 2013-01-02
 7:   2 2013-01-02     a 2013-01-02
 8:   2 2013-01-03     b 2013-01-02
 9:   2 2013-01-04     b 2013-01-02
```

Comment: Make sure your data is sorted by date first, or else the first line will give you something different to what you expect.